# Editing column content in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can i convert the whole format of my data frame column contents from`"TCGA-2F-A9KT-01A"` into `"TCGA-2F-A9KT"`. I want to maintain length of column values up to two "-".

```
oldcolumn<-c("TCGA-2F-A9KQ-01A", "TCGA-2F-A9KR-01A", "TCGA-2F-A9KT-01A" "TCGA-2F-A9KW-01A", "TCGA-4Z-AA7M-01A")
```

I want to remove "-01A" from the end of each .

new column should be

```
newcolumn<-c("TCGA-2F-A9KQ", "TCGA-2F-A9KR", "TCGA-2F-A9KT" "TCGA-2F-A9KW", "TCGA-4Z-AA7M")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sub` is a kind of find and replace, so first argument would be the pattern to be found, second argument would be the replacement and final argument is the vector where strings are contained

```
sub("-01A", "", oldcolumn)
[1] "TCGA-2F-A9KQ" "TCGA-2F-A9KR" "TCGA-2F-A9KT" "TCGA-2F-A9KW" "TCGA-4Z-AA7M"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `rename_with`

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~"TCGA-2F-A9KQ-01A", ~"TCGA-2F-A9KR-01A", 
                ~"TCGA-2F-A9KT-01A", ~"TCGA-2F-A9KW-01A", ~"TCGA-4Z-AA7M-01A",~"TCGA-4Z-AA7M-01B",
                1,1,1,1,1,1)

library(dplyr)
df |> 
  rename_with(~substr(.,1,nchar(.)-4), ends_with("01A"))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  `TCGA-2F-A9KQ` `TCGA-2F-A9KR` `TCGA-2F-A9KT` `TCGA-2F-A9KW` `TCGA-4Z-AA7M` `TCGA-4Z-AA7M-01B`
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>              <dbl>
1              1              1              1              1              1                  1
```

Answer (score 0):

A general solution (to keep threee sets of hypen-separated strings, discarding any further) could use `gsub` with a regular expression:

```r
oldcolumn  <- c("TCGA-2F-A9KQ-01A", "TCGA-2F-A9KR-01A", "TCGA-2F-A9KT-01A", "TCGA-2F-A9KW-01A", "TCGA-4Z-AA7M-01A")
newcolumn <- gsub("(([^-]+-){2}[^-]+)-.*", "\\1", oldcolumn)
newcolumn
# [1] "TCGA-2F-A9KQ" "TCGA-2F-A9KR" "TCGA-2F-A9KT" "TCGA-2F-A9KW" "TCGA-4Z-AA7M"
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be also another way using `stringr` package to remove the pattern from all strings:

```
stringr::str_remove_all(oldcolumn, pattern = "-01A")

[1] "TCGA-2F-A9KQ" "TCGA-2F-A9KR" "TCGA-2F-A9KT" "TCGA-2F-A9KW" "TCGA-4Z-AA7M"
```